# Failing installation of tensorpack

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorpack on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade tensorpack
Collecting tensorpack
  Using cached tensorpack-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tabulate (from tensorpack)
  Using cached tabulate-0.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting termcolor (from tensorpack)
  Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorpack)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorpack)
Collecting subprocess32 (from tensorpack)
  Using cached subprocess32-3.2.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    This backport is for Python 2.x only.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3vdwf8jw/subprocess32/
```

Do you know what might be causing this error?

---

Edit: With `pip3` it behaves the same.

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade tensorpack
Collecting tensorpack
  Using cached tensorpack-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack-numpy (from tensorpack)
  Using cached msgpack_numpy-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyzmq (from tensorpack)
  Using cached pyzmq-16.0.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting functools32 (from tensorpack)
  Using cached functools32-3.2.3-2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    This backport is for Python 2.7 only.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ut16f9e3/functools32/
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to install a python2 library on a python3 environment: `This backport is for Python 2.x only.` Have you tried explicitly calling `pip3` in your command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorpack worked for me, but the per-requisite were

1. Using a Virtual Environment

   virtualenv tensorpack
2. Secondly updating pip

   pip install --upgrade pip
3. Lastly not using "sudo"

   pip install tensorpack

Comment: Well, I was able to get it to work in a virtual environment, thanks :)